# Strange issue on window.name when using jQuery highlight effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight, effect

I'm frequently using jQuery highlight effect on some table data (td) cell.
I just realized that when I use this effect, the window.name value magically changes in "data-ec" value after highlight  effect is complete.
This behavior gives me some problems, because I need to check window.name that I previously set.

I'm using code as following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='jquery-1.6.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src='jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function PlayIssue() {
            //Set Window Name
            window.name = 'myWindowName';
            // Get RIGHT window name
            alert(window.name); // popup shows "myWindowName" as window name

            //Play jQuery Effect on TD cell
            var myCell = $("#TableID tr[id='row_ID'] td:nth-child(1)");
            myCell.effect("highlight", { color: '#FFA500' }, 8000);

            //get WRONG window name
            alert(window.name);  // popup shows "data-ec" as window name
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="TableID" border="1">
        <tr id="row_ID">
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Call JS Function to play issue
        PlayIssue();
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea for this behavior ?
This issue happens on IE 9/10 (tried only these), but not in Firefox and Chrome.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to show us some markup to explain "data-ec" and "window.name" as there's nothing in your question that tells us anything about them.

Comment: Hi Archer, thanks for quick response. I've added code example. Bye

Comment: Even if by policy I cannot update the jQuery plugin, I've just tried with the version jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js, but the issue remains with the following new name for window "data-ui-effects-opacity" instead of "data-ec".

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this an issue?

Comment: It is an issue for me because I need to preserve window name for the entire user session to check usage of back/forward buttons of the browser, with a custom control based on window name. Do I satisfied your curiosity ?

Comment: It does satisfy it, thanks.  Just use a different global variable in that case - one that *isn't* modified by anything else.

Comment: I cannot use a global var because the control on window name is not mine, but it's introduced by a framework I using. I simply remove jQuery effect to solve problem. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep the effect (this is lame, but will work) `var windowName = window.name;` before the effect, and `window.name = windowName;` after the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with replacing 'effect' function, with 'animate' function.

I used the following function:

```
function flashColor(obj) {
    if (obj.length) {
        var originalColor = obj.css('backgroundColor');
        obj.animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFA500' }, 1000).delay(700).animate({ backgroundColor: originalColor }, 1000);
    }
}
```